# Problems installing certain libraries in python using pip in Spyder

Tags: python, pip, spyder

I’ve been running into the same error message with multiple libraries, not all libraries but randomly.
All I could find here and on other equation boards was that I need to upgrade my pip, it’s upgraded to the max (22.1.2) but I still get the same error, no with the added “WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.”

So this is what I get when I try to install pyinstaller

```
pip install pyinstaller
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached pyinstaller-5.1-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting pefile>=2017.8.1
  Using cached pefile-2022.5.30.tar.gz (72 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32-ctypes>=0.2.0 in d:\program files\spyder\pkgs (from pyinstaller) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in d:\program files\spyder\pkgs (from pyinstaller) (61.2.0)
Collecting altgraph
  Using cached altgraph-0.17.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting pyinstaller-hooks-contrib>=2021.4
  Using cached pyinstaller_hooks_contrib-2022.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (231 kB)
Collecting future
  Using cached future-0.18.2.tar.gz (829 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [6 lines of output]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\tomer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-01zbu624\future_a521b799a85941e08b0fd94b59c7d89a\setup.py", line 86, in <module>
      import src.future
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Encountered error while generating package metadata.

See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Are you running `pip` inside Spyder's IPython console?

Comment: Yes... It works fine with most packages, am i not support to?

Comment: You should avoid that and run pip or conda in a system terminal instead.